# Jenkins Error : from queue but master went off-line before the task's worker thread started. No termination trace available

Tags: jenkins

When I hit build now nothing is getting triggered , when i check the system log i got the below

Jun 22, 2022 12:03:12 PM WARNING hudson.model.Executor resetWorkUnit
Executor #-1 for master grabbed hudson.model.queue.WorkUnit@2ed503b9[work=application_versioning] from queue but master went off-line before the task's worker thread started. No termination trace available.

Comment: Do you have any offline master nodes?

Comment: no, its hosted on only one node and i am able to launch jenkins on the same host successfully